# Write EEPROM arrays on Arduino

Tags: arduino, eeprom

I want to write the time at which the button was turned on or off.

Every time that someone turns on the switch, Arduino would store this information.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <EEPROM.h> // library to access the onboard EEPROM

const int debounceTime = 15000; // debounce time in microseconds 
int buttonPin = 5; // pushbutton connected to digital pin 5
int eeAddress = 0; // Address in the eeprom to store the data.
volatile unsigned long time; // variable to store the time since the program started
volatile boolean timeRecorded = false; // used to know when to save value
volatile unsigned long last_Rising; // used to debounce button press

void setup()
{
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);      // sets the digital pin 5 as input
  attachInterrupt(buttonPin, debounce, RISING);
}

void loop() 
{
  // Only want write when a time is saved
  if(valueRecorded)
  {        
    EEPROM.put(eeAddress, time);
    valueRecorded = false;
  }
}

void debounce()
{
  if((micros() - last_Rising) >= debouncing_time) 
  {
    getTime(); // call actual method to fetch and save time
    last_Rising = micros();
  }
}

void getTime()
{
  time = millis();
  valueRecorded = true;
}
```

This answer makes the following assumptions:

-An Arduino Uno is being used.
-A momentary switch (or button) is connected to digital pin 5 in such a way that a 5v signal will be applied to pin 5 when the switch is in the "on" position and 0v signal will be applied to pin 5 when the switch is in the "off" position.
-Your goal is to write into the onboard eeprom the time at which the button changed state for the last time it occured.

This code uses an interrupt to catch the transition from "off" to "on". The mechanical nature of switches requires debouncing the input (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce).

To read the value from the eeprom you would similarly use `EEPROM.get( eeAddress, time)` this would put the value saved in the eeprom in the variable `time`.

This code also makes no provision to  deal with actual calendar time.There is a time library in the Arduino playground (http://playground.arduino.cc/code/time) though it is apparantly out of date. A "Time" library is linked to on that page and has documentation on how to use it to provide calendar time, however, the time would need to be set and synchronized each time the Arduino is restarted.